# pyOpenSSL RSA private keys encrypted with AES 256

Tags: python, encryption, openssl, pyopenssl

In pyOpenSSL i haven't been able to find a way to encrypt a RSA private key with AES 256 just yet, been looking all over the place for this but cant seem to find a way.

Before i used OpenSSL to get the key and ca/cl certificates but now im opting to make an application where i need to handle the pfx-file in certain ways.

In OpenSSL i used to do the following:

openssl pkcs12 -in file.pfx -nocerts -out key.key

after that i did:

openssl rsa -aes256 -key.key -out encrypted.key

is there anything similar in pyOpenSSL using crypto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I solved this. But for anyone wondering, this is what I did:

```
import os
import shutil
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA


def encrypt(old_key, new_key, passphrase):
        key = RSA.importKey(open(old_key, 'rb').read())

        with open(new_key, 'wb') as f:
                pem_key = key.export_key(format='PEM', passphrase=passphrase, pkcs=8, protection='PBKDF2WithHMAC-SHA1AndAES256-CBC')

                f.write(pem_key)
                f.close()

        if os.path.exists(old_key):
                os.remove(old_key)


encryptAES('path_to_old_key', 'path_to_new:key.key', 'supersecretpassword')
```

One question still remaining is if there's anyway to output the encryption info done in python similar to OpenSSL?

If you run `openssl rsa -aes256 -in old.key -out new.key`

The key will return attributes in the beginning like such:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-256-CBC
Key here...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

However when I export the private key in Python I just get:

```
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
Key here...
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Is there anyway to display these attributes with `pycryptodome`?

Comment: The first (what openssl returns) is an encrypted private key in PKCS#1 format, the latter (what your code returns) is an encrypted private key in PKCS#8 format, which your export returns because of `pkcs=8`. Try `pkcs=1` (which is even the default), see [`export_key()`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/public_key/rsa.html#Crypto.PublicKey.RSA.RsaKey.export_key).

Comment: Interesting! If i change the PKCS-format to PKCS#1 it doesnt seem to let me use AES-256-CBC as the protection method.

Instead it uses Triple DES. 

`pem_key = key.export_key(format='PEM', passphrase=passphrase, pkcs=1, protection='PBKDF2WithHMAC-SHA1AndAES256-CBC')`

outputs to: 

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----  
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED  
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC

Comment: From the `export_key()` documentation: *...Specifying a value for protection is only meaningful for PKCS#8...The supported schemes for PKCS#8 are listed in the Crypto.IO.PKCS8 module...*: Seems like PyCryptodome for PKCS#1 only supports *DES-EDE3-CBC*.

Comment: Yeah, just read that as Well after Looking through the documentation. I suppose that it isnt necessary, just convenient and more of a reminder of the encryption when overviewing the key Itself. As long as its encrypted with AES-256 I’m more or less happy. Otherwise, do you by any chance know of a module that supports AES-256-CBC over pkcs#1?

Comment: Well, to verify i guess i could use OpenSSL.

`openssl asn1parse -in my_private.key`

Comment: *Cryptography* has [`BestAvailableEncryption`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/serialization/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.BestAvailableEncryption). Currently the key is encrypted with AES-256-CBC for PKCS#1, but this isn't configurable. From the documentation: *Encrypt using the best available encryption for a given key. This is a curated encryption choice and the algorithm may change over time.* But maybe it is enough for you.

Comment: Interesting implementation, i will try that!